# Where is the best location for this function? C++

Tags: c++, oop, class, function

Is it alright to have a function that is not a part of any specific class when using an object-oriented approach. In my case, I would like to have a `check_collision()` function that takes two `SDL_Rect`s as arguments and then returns a `true` or `false`. The `SDL_Rect`s would be found inside existing objects like a character class or a tile class. Is there a good place to put this function? Am I overlooking a better approach to this problem?

Comment: Seems appropriate.  A free function in the vein of `operator==`.  Are you asking specifically "where" in code to put it, or just asking if a free function is the correct approach?

Comment: Free functions are as good as methods, if not better. Leads to better encapsulation.

Comment: Yes, I'm just wondering if a free function is an acceptable approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post up the only dissenting answer (for now).  Since you have an already existing type (`SDL_Rect`) that you don't own (its included from a 3rd party), I would suggest to implement this as a free function as you have suggested in your original answer.  In my opinoin, this will be the cleanest approach for your direct question.

```
bool check_collision(const SDL_Rect& l, const SDL_Rect& r);
```

Your other option is to write a class that wraps `SDL_Rect` and provides collision detection, like this:

```
class CD_SDL_Rect
{
public:
    bool check_collision(const SDL_Rect& r);
private:
    SDL_Rect r_;
};
```

But that seems like overkill for this particular case.

If you already had a `DisplayableObject` class that all displayable objects derived from I may be swayed to suggest adding this as a member, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: No, there is currently no inheriting going on but if that's the best approach i would have no problem rewriting it a bit to accommodate. Of the two, what would you find to be the ideal solution?

Comment: Inheritance should be used when you have a strong reason for it to be.  If your overall design required that all "displayable objects" have a consistent interface but act in a polymorphic way then it is a good choice.  To do it because you want to see if two rectangles collide is not a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I would use for object oriented collision detection would be to have the object have a check_collision() function that takes in another of its type, and performs the check that way.  you can then use polymorphism and inheritance to define your shape tree and perform all checks through a single function

Comment: That seems like a good idea. The thing is, I'm checking to see if a tile has collided with the camera to see if it should be rendered. As these are obviously two different types of objects, do you still think this is the best method? I'm sorry if this sounds like I'm attacking your solution, I just want to make sure you understand my problem. Thank you.

Comment: It certainly can be used in that way, you would simply need to give your camera an object that can collide with things.  You can put it in a special list, or just perform the collisions checks with it manually, rather than in a usual physics update loop, to avoid doing physics on the camera itself when it collides

Answer (score 0):

I would have some kind of "DisplayObject" class from which all of your displayable elements that you might want to check collision on are inherited.  Then, place the collision check inside that.

Comment: Thank you, I think that's what Dan was saying with the Polymorphism approach. I appreciate the more specific explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Using a free function is a valid approach. Declare it inside a namespace so you do not populate the global scope.
It is better if the function can be declared as not friend of the class.